# We are moving to Brisbane and hold 482 Subclass Visa, Do we need to pay school fees for grade 1 in state school?

Tags: visa

We are moving to Brisbane and hold 482 Subclass Visa, Do we need to pay school fees for grade 1 kid in state schools

1. if yes how much?
2. Is there any e

Thanks

Comment: *"Is there any e"* — There probably *is* MDMA to be found in Brisbane, but this isn't the appropriate place to ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the 482 visa exempts you from fees. See [this pdf](https://ppr.qed.qld.gov.au/attachment/de-international-schedule-of-visa-subclasses-and-enrolment-conditions.pdf). This document is found on Queensland's Policies and Procedures website, but I found it by searching on [Education Queensland International](https://eqi.com.au/) website which has lots of information.